# Creating a custom filter in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a relatively basic filter called "format" that removes the first two characters of a string and the last two characters of the string.  I figured the best way was to return a substring like so:

```
var tickReg = angular.module('ticketRegister', ['ngRoute']);

tickReg.filter('format', function(){
    return function(input)
    {
        return input.substring(2, input.length-2);      
    };  
});
```

Only problem is...it's not working :(

Here's the html:

```
<span><em><strong>{{guests.server | format}}</strong></em></span>
```

Any insight?

The reason I am doing this is because, for some reason, when I use this:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" ng-model="guests.server">
                        <option>Dylan</option>
                        <option>Ebens</option>
                        <option>Lincoln</option>
                        <option>Mickey</option>
                        <option>Server 1</option>
                        <option>Server 2</option>
                        <option>Server 3</option>
                        <option>Server 4</option>
                        <option>Manager</option>
                    </select>
```

it stores the server name inside of quotation marks and square brackets (i.e. ["Dylan"], instead of just Dylan).  Here is the corresponding controller for this ng-model:

```
function CalculatorController($scope)
{
$scope.guests = 
  {
    adults : 0,
    children : 0,
    drinks : 0,
    server : undefined
  };
}
```

Thanks!
-Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see square brackets is that you have `multiple` on your select. So it's actually a select used to choose **several** servers, and the associated model is thus an **array** containing all the chosen servers.

You shouldn't use a filter to access your server array. You should use

```
guests.server[0]
```

for example to access the first selected server. And an ng-repeat to iterate over `guests.server` and display them all. BTW, the variable should really be named `servers`, since it's an array containing several servers.

If your intention is to select one and only one server, then don't use the multiple attribute on the `select`.